# Remove XML declaration using msxml2 IXMLDOMDocument2

Tags: c++, xml, msxml, xmldom

I want to remove XML declaration only from an XML using C++

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

Then I want to add this line and resave the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
```

All I have and know how to do it load the xml document

```
hr = IXMLDOMDocument->load(vstrfilename, &status);
```

using the `IXMLDOMDocument2` interface of `msxml2`

How can I achieve this ?
My programming environment is `borland c++ builder 6`

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<? some text ?>` is a processing instruction. The node is of type `NODE_PROCESSING_INSTRUCTION`.

Retrieve the node as the first child of the document, using `get_childNodes` and delete it with `removeChild`.

Then, use `createProcessingInstruction` for the new encoding and use `insertBefore` (with the new first child) to add it to the document.